# Having trouble with pointers

Tags: c++

I have some trouble with displaying data from a couple of pointer chars.

```
int main()
{
    char *arr = new char();
    for (int t = 0;t < 10;t++)
    {
        int size = Generator::GetInstance()->Generate(arr);
        for (int generateChars = 0;generateChars < size;generateChars++)
        {
            std::cout << &arr[generateChars] << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

and the Generator class

```
int Generator::Generate(char *ar)
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    int size = (rand() % 10)+1;
    arr = new char[size];
    for (int t = 0;t < size;t++)
    {
        int path = rand() % 4;
        switch (path)
        {
            case 0:
                arr[t] = 'U';
                break;
            case 1:
                arr[t] = 'R';
                break;
            case 2:
                arr[t] = 'D';
                break;
            case 3:
                arr[t] = 'L';
                break;
        }
    }
    arr[size] = '\0';
    *ar = *arr;
    return size;
}
```

What am I doing wrong this time and why is it displaying junk data each time I am trying something. Sorry if this is something that is answered before already.

Comment: Do you come from a Java background, by chance?

Comment: You are allocating `arr` in main and then again in `Generate`, this is going to cause problems.

Comment: The `Generate` function is responsible for allocating the memory.  So there is no need to do this in `main`:  `char *arr = new char();`  In addition, your `Generate` function can do absolutely nothing with that passed-in pointer to change it, since you passed the pointer by value.

Comment: Assuming that you want an array of strings of a random combination of U, R, D, and L then you really *really* **really** need to look into `std::string` and `std::vector` and stop using `new` directly. Also, you're not freeing up the memory afterward using `delete` which you need to do.

Comment: Also, where did `arr` come from in the `Generate` function.  Please don't say it's a global variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your "Generate" functions parameter from a pointer to a pointer reference:

```
int Generator::Generate(char *& ar)
```

And change the line:

```
*ar = *arr;
```

that is in your "Generate" function to:

```
ar = arr;
```

Also remember to clear any dynamic memory that "ar" may point to, when "Generate" is called.

I tested this code and it worked for me...

**EDIT** In the "for" loop that displays your array, change the line:

```
std::cout << &arr[generateChars] << " ";
```

to:

```
std::cout << arr[generateChars] << " ";
```

Comment: Thanks. Helped quite a lot.

Comment: No, problem. I'm glad to be of service. :)

Comment: One more thing, remove the "address of" (&) operator from the line that displays the character array:  `std::cout << &arr[generateChars] << " ";`

Answer (score 3):

If you try to print a `char *`, C++ assumes that it is a C-style null-terminated string.

It appears that you are allocating (and passing a pointer into) a `char` array without a terminating null -- so, the I/O library will follow that character with all the junk data that happens to be in memory, until it happens to encounter a null byte.

A simple solution is to pass either a `char` or a `char &`, instead of a `char *`, so that the I/O will correctly interpret it as a single character.

However, that will not fix your memory leaks, which are a separate problem.  If you want to use C++ for anything beyond toy programs, you should make a habit of `delete`-ing anything allocated by `new` when you no longer need it.

Finally, as mentioned in comments, your code is very non-idiomatic for C++.  It is actually terribly educational to play around with low-level code like this, but the standard library has `std::string`'s and all sorts of containers that make it easier to manage your memory correctly, so make sure you learn how to use them, as well as understanding the lower-level features they are built on...